# is there any wayout to set init parameter in servletconfig or servletContext object?

Tags: java, servlets, set, servletconfig, init-parameters

if i want to modify init-parameter value in any of ServletContext or ServletConfig.
any want it to be updated after servlet is destroyed by container.
is there any wayout?

Comment: Besides altering the value in web.xml?  Are you asking to pro grammatically update the web application's WEB-INF/web.xml file's init parameter(s) for a given servlet based on some condition you detect at runtime?

Comment: yes thats what i want if it is possible.

Answer (score -3):

you can set params programmatically while accessing the `ServletConfig`

```
config.getServletContext().setInitParameter("foo", "bar")
```

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch05s09.html